# TControlState.csDesignerHide vs. TControlStyle.csNoDesignVisible

Tags: delphi, vcl

The VCL seems to offer two mechanisms for hiding controls from form designers : `TControlState.csDesignerHide` and `TControlStyle.csNoDesignVisible`.

What's the difference between them as far as the IDE is concerned? Which should you use when?

Comment: The *state* one doesn't seem to be very much offered. (1) - It is not documented. (2) - The only code which includes/excludes it (`SetDesignVisible` of 'TControl' and 'TWinControl') is documented as *"is used internally by Delphi during form design"*. (3) - Not used by the VCL, the only code that ever calls `SetDesignVisible` is in 'ribbons'. I'd try to use the 'control style'.

Comment: @Sertac `SetDesignVisible` is the property setter and is indeed the only routine setting the flag, but I think you're drawing the wrong conclusion from it: it's more important where and whether the flag is being consulted instead of being set.

Comment: @NGLN - You're wrong, `SetDesignVisible` is not a property setter. Additionally, I'm saying it's not used by VCL, where the flag is being tested has no importance unless it's set by some code.

Comment: @Sertac Ok, it's not a property setter... ;-) But I mean to say that although the VCL doesn't set the flag, component builders might do. It's about the framework that provides instead of the framework that uses. I don't think there is much setting of the `csNoDesignVisible` flag in the VCL either.

Comment: `csNoDesignVisible` is used in a few places, PopupDataList, ActionClientItem, ActionPopupMenu, TabSheet, notebook Page and again in ribbon are the ones I can find. Of course developers may use `csDesignerHide`, I didn't conclude/say otherwise (just suggested against it). But IMO, either it should be evident what it does, or it should be documented to be able to use it. It's only after your answer I have some slight idea to its purpose. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Summary

Use `TControlState.csDesignerHide` to prevent the control from drawing.

Use `TControlStyle.csNoDesignVisible` to mimic runtime behaviour of the `Visible` property.

#### Elaboration

Nice question! There simply must be a difference between them, so I did a little investigation.

Searching for usage in the `Controls` unit, we find that:

- `TControlState.csDesignerHide` is used in: `TControl.InvalidateControl`, `TWinControl.UpdateShowing`, `TWinControl.PaintHandler`, `TWinControl.PaintControls`,
- in addition to those methods, `TControlStyle.csNoDesignVisible` is also used in: `TControl.Show`, `TControl.Repaint`, `TControl.CMVisibleChanged`, `TWinControl.AlignControls`, `TWinControl.ControlAtPos`, `TWinControl.CMVisibleChanged`, `TWinControl.GetControlExtents`, `TWinControl.CalcConstraints`, `TWinControl.CanAutoSize`.

Thus `TControlState.csDesignerHide` is only used in painting operations whereas `TControlStyle.csNoDesignVisible` is also used in position and alignment operation.

In other words, use:

- `TControlState.csDesignerHide` if you only want control over visibility,
- `TControlStyle.csNoDesignVisible` if you also want control over presence.

Furthermore, `TControlStyle.csNoDesignVisible` works only in conjuction with the Visible property. It has no effect when Visible is set True. (Normally, the Visible property only affects runtime behaviour).

To illustrate the difference, hereby three screen shots of a form designer. On the form are placed from left to right: a "`TStyleControl`" with a property controlling `TControlStyle.csNoDesignVisible`, a Panel, a `"TStateControl"` with a property controlling `TControlState.csDesignerHide` and another Panel, all with the Align property set to `alLeft`:

[image]

1. All with default settings
2. `StateControl1.DesignerHide = True`
3. `StyleControl1.NoDesignVisible = True` and `StyleControl1.Visible = False`

Comment: Thanks! *TControlStyle.csNoDesignVisible works only in conjuction with the Visible property* Ah - the screenshot explains it best!