# Delphi Rad Studio, is there any way to hide GUI components in the gui editor

Tags: user-interface, delphi, delphi-2010

i was wondering if there was any way that you could hide certain GUI components in the GUI editor, in rad studio. not actually hiding the component on run with .hide() function, i mean just so that i can work on the other components and design. for example if i have a panel that pops up that is reused over and over again with certain elements but that covers my screen i cant work on the other components. is the only solution to create the components dynamically?

Comment: give more explanation please/

Comment: There is no option to hide visual components in the Form Editor itself (unless you write your own components to use the `TControlState.csDesignerHide` and `TControlStyle.csNoDesignVisible` flags, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068623/).  Otherwise, about all you can do is just move components around as needed to get them out of way, even going as far as moving them beyond the boundaries of their containing Form/Parent if needed.

Comment: thanks so much, thats gonna be annoying but ill make a plan

Comment: In the case of the panel, why not use a PageControl?

Comment: Another tip is, if you want to select a visual component that you cannot see use Object inspector to find it.

Comment: Installing the GExperts you will have and option to hide non-visual components, so you can work with the underlying controls, and then show them again.

Comment: Use the send to back functionality.